# Next.js useEffect doesnt work. and console log display on terminal instead of web browser

Tags: next.js, react-hooks, console.log

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession, getProviders } from "next-auth/react";

const Nav = () => {
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("deneme: ")
  },[])
  
  console.log("zzzzzzzzz")

  return (
    <nav className='flex-between w-full mb-16 pt-3'>
      blabla
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

I just want to test if I'm able to get data but I realized that I can't even console.log in useEffect(). then  couldn't find any solution.I use "use client" for client side rendering. and also I can't display consolelogs in web browser. can someone help me?

Comment: It is a client component and something this issue occur. The production build is this issue free.

Comment: Could I know your you're using Next12 or Next13?

Comment: I have the same problem as you.. What's your node and next versions ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.